# pgAdmin4: need to restore database every time I run a query - how to fix this error?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am a Mac OS user and I am using .tar file for my database source on pgAdmin 4.
I discovered that every time I run a query, the data gets lost, and I need to restore the data before I execute the next query. For example,

After executing:

```
SELECT * FROM film;
```

I need to restore data from my .tar file again to execute:

```
SELECT * FROM film WHERE amount=7.99;
```

If I don't restore my data before I execute my second query, the second query only returns an empty table.

How should I fix this error?

Thank you,

Comment: check rules and views - the only explanation that comes to my mind - you have a rule or view that instead of select you do delete

Answer (score 0):

check whether "film" is not a rule and view. It could be smth like:

```
t=# create table t (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into t select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# create or replace function f() returns table (i int) as ' begin return query delete from t returning *; end; ' language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# create or replace view v as select * from f();
CREATE VIEW

t=# select * from v;
 i
---
 1
(1 row)

t=# select * from v;
 i
---
(0 rows)
```